# There was an error reflecting property Member when using the new keyword on an abstract class virtual property

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, overriding, abstract-class

I would like to use an abstract base class (call it **AbstractBaseClassA**) which holds only one property (virtual - **Property1**) of type List of another abstract base class (Call it **AbstractBaseClassB**).

I have another class which should inherit from **AbstractBaseClassA** (call it **superClassA**) and implement the property but as a List of class (type) that inherit from the **AbstractBaseClassB** (call it **superClassB**).

I would like the property of **superClassA** - **Property1** **override** the property of  **AbstractBaseClassA** -  I can't use the **override** it because it is a List of elements that aren't from the same class (but from inherited class) and as so - it doesn't implement the abstract class, and when I use the "new" keyword - I get an error message claiming:

"There was an error reflecting property Member Property1: superClassA.Property1 of type System.Collections.Generic.List'1 hides base class member AbstractBaseClassA.Property1 of type System.Collections.Generic.List'1".
The error occures when I try to serialize xml to **superClassA** object (I removed the xml Attributes).

What should I do in order to make it work ?

This is my code:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClassA
{
       [XmlIgnore]
       public virtual List<AbstractBaseClassB> Property1 {get; set;}
}

public Abstract class AbstractBaseClassB
{
    public string simpleProperty1111 {get; set;}
    /*constructors*/
    public AbstractBaseClassB(){}
    public AbstractBaseClassB(string prop1)
    {
        simpleProperty1111 = prop1;
    }
}

public class superClassB : AbstractBaseClassB
{   
    public string simplePropety2222 {get; set;};
    /*constructors*/
    public superClassB() : base(){}
    public superClassB(string prop22222, string prop11111) : base(prop11111)
    {
        simplePropety2222 = prop22222;
    }
    
}

public class superClassA : AbstractBaseClassA
{
    public new List<superClassB> Property1 {get; set;}
}
```

SOLVED : I've used the "virtual" (in abstract class) and the "new" keyword  (in the inherited class) and I've changed the XmlAttribute over the virtual property with [XmlIgnore]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: code in the question is updated: I've used the "virtual" (in abstract class) and the "new" keyword  (in the inherited class) and I've changed the XmlAttribute over the virtual property with [XmlIgnore]